# Unable to specify dynamic variable in function argument in PHP

Tags: php

Doing a bit of coding, and wanted to set a default value of today's date for an argument in a function that I have. However, having a bit of problems having it work and have it still be dynamic. This is current setup, where I have static values assigned to certain function arguments.

`private function search($text, $startDate = "2012-10-19", $endDate = "2012-10-20") {
//code goes here
}`

Not what I want, but it's what works, and the IDE doesnt' complain.

This is what I've tried, with the corresponding complaints from the interpreter

`private function search($text, $startDate = $this->getCurrentDate(), $endDate = "2012-10-20") {
//code goes here
}`

returns "syntax error, unexpected $this", where getCurrentDate refers to a private function that only returns a string. Same co-occurrence happens when I call a variable declared in class scope (minus the brackets at the end of getCurrentDate of course). Utilizing static brings up "Undefined class constant 'self::getCurrentDate ' ", regardless of whether I call it as a function or a class scope variable which is odd since I've defined it as such.

```
    private static function getDate() {
    return "foo";
}
```

and

```
private static $getTodaysDate = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("M"), date("d"), date("Y")));
```

in my two different attempts. Of course this

`private function search($text, $startDate = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("M"), date("d"), date("Y"))), $endDate = "2012-10-20") {
//code goes here
}`

doesn't work at all.

So I'm sure it's just some obvious thing I'm missing, but I cannot see why PHP is not allowing me to do this without declaring a static string, or if I'm running against a limitation of the language. Anyone have any ideas as to what's the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values for function parameters can not be dynamic!
From the [PHP Manual](http://se.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) on default values for function parameters:

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call.

What you could do is set the default parameter to `null` and then in your function check if the parameter is `null` and if so overwrite it with the current date.

```
private function search($text, $startDate = null, $endDate = "2012-10-20") {
    if ($startDate === null) $startDate = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("M"), date("d"), date("Y"));
}
```

Comment: Well thats' mildly embarrassing, but explains why its' not working. Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: We all have our weak moments. :)